# How to extract explicit content from org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-test

I was writing a test by sample [from here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/). The test was intended to check, that root's username is equal to it's username from database and looked following:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;

...

@Test
   public void rootUserPresent() throws Exception {

      ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(get("/user/root"));

      result
         .andExpect(status().isOk())
         .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$.screenName", is(userRepository.getRootUser().getScreenName())))
         ;

   }
```

First I wrote this test, it was causing ClassNotFound exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/InvalidPathException
```

So, I was thinking the system wishes to report me about wrong path but can't find class for an exception. So, I included `com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:1.1.0` dependency. After that the test just began to be PASSED.

So, I came to suspicion, that test result is wrong positive.

My question is: how explicitly extract JSON value with the same instruments I have here, and check it's value literally?

**PS**

JSON result is following:

```
{
   id: 1,
   roles: [
   {
      name: "USER"
   },
   {
      name: "ADMIN"
   }
],
   firstName: null,
   lastName: null,
   screenName: "root",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something like this:

```
// wrapper to extract result from the response
AssignmentResult result = new AssignmentResult();

// perform request 
mockMvc.perform(
        get("/myApiEndpoint")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        )
.andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$object.parent.id", is(parent.getId())))
    .andDo(assignTo("$object.id", result)); // (**)

Integer objectIdFromResult = (Integer)result.getValue();    // (++)
```

`assignTo` is a custom ResultHandler I wrote:

```
/**
 * Spring ResultHandler for MVC testing, allows the assignment of a JSON path to a variable.
 */
public class AssignmentResultHandler implements ResultHandler {

    private final JsonPath jsonPath;
    private final AssignmentResult assignmentResult;

    public static ResultHandler assignTo(String jsonPath, AssignmentResult assignmentResult) {
        return new AssignmentResultHandler(JsonPath.compile(jsonPath), assignmentResult);
    }

    protected AssignmentResultHandler(JsonPath jsonPath, AssignmentResult assignmentResult) {
        this.jsonPath = jsonPath;
        this.assignmentResult = assignmentResult;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(MvcResult result) throws Exception {
        String resultString = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        assignmentResult.setValue(jsonPath.read(resultString));
    }
}
```

When creating the new `AssignmentResultHandler`, you pass in an `AssignmentResult` wrapper (**). When the `AssignmentResultHandler` is triggered (`handle` runs),
it set the value of the `AssignmentResult`. After the request is done, you can unwrap the value from there (++).

Here's the AssignmentResult wrapper:

```
public class AssignmentResult {
    private Object value;

    /**
     * Set the result value
     * @param value result value
     */
    protected void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the result value
     * @return the result value
     */
    public Object getValue() {
        return this.value;
    } 
}
```